# Position of axis titles in ggplot, relative placement?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone have any insight into the placement of the axis titles in ggplot?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point() + ylab("HP") + ylim(50,350) + xlim(10,35)
```

[image]

You can see the P in HP is below the top of the 200. And likewise the m on mpg is almost in line (or partly overlapping) with the 0 on 20 leaving the g in the middle of 20 and 25. I would have thought the middle of the gap between the H and P would have been in the middle (vertically) of the 2 in 200. If that makes sense.

Adding a few spaces to the label ("   HP") helps to fix it. Obviously the title is being centered relative to some co-ordinates, my guess is a 'box' that goes all the way to the bottom of the x labels (for the y title) and to the left of the y labels (for the x title). When having them relative to the actual plotting area would be more desirable.

Is this achievable?

Comment: The axis title will be aligned to the panel (i.e., plot region) in the next version of ggplot2.

Comment: This has come up before. See [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/192). I've been eagerly awaiting this one.

Comment: Ah right, thanks kohske and joran. Not sure if I was googling the wrong thing but I found no reference to it anywhere :/ out of interest, is there a workaround atm?

Comment: Best option might be to install the dev version.

Comment: Except for manual adjustment, the only workaround is using the dev version

Comment: Make sure neither of you type google into google okay.

Comment: @kohske If only I could leverage this psychic connection to absorb some of your ggplot2 expertise! :)

Comment: The workaround is to tweak the justification with (for example) `+opts(axis.title.y = theme_text(vjust=0.6))`: you may want to tweak `size`, `hjust` while you're at it

Answer (score 3):

Per @Hadley's comment, as of version 0.9.0 this bug-let has been fixed:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    ylab("HP") + 
    ylim(50,350) + 
    xlim(10,35)
```

produces:

[image]